# Image in header blocking link in nav bar

Tags: html, css

I got an image in the middle of my navbar which is blocking my link, I made a bit of code below to show that. I tried to fix this with z-index's but it keeps blocking my link.
I can't place the image in the nav bar itself because of the rest of my code (which is not in this snippet). I think it should be solved if I get the absolute image behind the `<a>` but I can't get that done with z-index's

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("nav a").click(function(event){
        $("article").removeClass("slide_1");
        $("article").removeClass("slide_2");
        $("article").removeClass("slide_3");
            var clickedId = event.target.id;
            $('article').addClass("slide_"+clickedId);
        });
    });
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffe7d9;
}

nav{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fed5b7;
}

nav ul{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li{
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 35px;
}

nav li a{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav li a.no-background{
  background-image: none !important;
}

img.headerlogo{
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  height: 200%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

article{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.slide_1{
  background-color: red;
}

.slide_2{
  background-color: green;
}

.slide_3{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav id="menu">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/90" class="headerlogo">
        <ul>  
            <li><a id="1">Link1</a></li>
            <li class="logo"><a id="2">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a id="3">Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<article>
</article>
```

Comment: You want put image under menu?

Comment: Heads up! `ul` and `ol` should only contain `li` elements.

Comment: where you want to put your image ?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Oh ye sorry, in my original code I have the `<img>` outside the `<ul>` but did it wrong in the code made for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
nav{
        z-index:9;}
        img.headerlogo{
          z-index:-1;
    opacity:0.5;
        }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("nav a").click(function(event){
        $("article").removeClass("slide_1");
        $("article").removeClass("slide_2");
        $("article").removeClass("slide_3");
            var clickedId = event.target.id;
            $('article').addClass("slide_"+clickedId);
        });
    });
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffe7d9;
}

nav{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fed5b7;
  z-index:9;
}

nav ul{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li{
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 35px;
}

nav li a{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav li a.no-background{
  background-image: none !important;
}

img.headerlogo{
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  height: 200%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0.5;
}

article{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.slide_1{
  background-color: red;
}

.slide_2{
  background-color: green;
}

.slide_3{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/90" class="headerlogo">
            <li><a id="1">Link1</a></li>
            <li class="logo"><a id="2">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a id="3">Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<article>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I didn't try negative z-indexes yet.

Comment: @Minegolfer Most Welcome..!!

Answer (score 0):

Put img tage outside and change css for class `headerlogo`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("nav a").click(function(event){
        $("article").removeClass("slide_1");
        $("article").removeClass("slide_2");
        $("article").removeClass("slide_3");
            var clickedId = event.target.id;
            $('article').addClass("slide_"+clickedId);
        });
    });
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffe7d9;
}

nav{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fed5b7;
}

nav ul{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li{
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 35px;
}

nav li a{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav li a.no-background{
  background-image: none !important;
}

img.headerlogo{
  position: relative;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

article{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.slide_1{
  background-color: red;
}

.slide_2{
  background-color: green;
}

.slide_3{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="1">Link1</a></li>
            <li class="logo"><a id="2">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a id="3">Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/90" class="headerlogo">
<article>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `z-index:-1` to `z-index: 1;` and `z-index:1; position:relative;` to `nav`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("nav a").click(function(event){
        $("article").removeClass("slide_1");
        $("article").removeClass("slide_2");
        $("article").removeClass("slide_3");
            var clickedId = event.target.id;
            $('article').addClass("slide_"+clickedId);
        });
    });
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffe7d9;
}

nav{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fed5b7;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;  
  position: relative;
}

nav li{
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 35px;
}

nav li a{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav li a.no-background{
  background-image: none !important;
}

img.headerlogo{
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  height: 200%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

article{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.slide_1{
  background-color: red;
}

.slide_2{
  background-color: green;
}

.slide_3{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav id="menu">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/90" class="headerlogo">
        <ul>            
            <li><a id="1">Link1</a></li>
            <li class="logo"><a id="2">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a id="3">Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<article>
</article>
```